How to include quarto theme in published document on GitHub Pages
I have a quarto document named test.qmd:
---
title: "test"
theme: quartz
---

## Quarto

I followed the instructions here to setup publishing to GitHub.
Then I ran:
quarto publish gh-pages test.qmd

But the published content does not include the theme. However, if I open the html file locally the theme is applied.
How do I include the theme and any other CSS when publishing to GitHub pages?
